# Index.html on flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there a way to communicate between index.html file on the flutter web folder to dart main files, i need to run a javascript code to get an output and may be display it on the main.dart.

Answer (score 1):

Dart.js is a built-in library that can interop with JavaScript.

Create a JS file in the web directory and add some functions to it. It calls the function from the global Window execution context. You can define a top level function, or define values directly on window.

```
function alertMessage(text) {
alert(text)
}

window.logger = (flutter_value) => {
   console.log({ js_context: this, flutter_value });
}
```

Make JS available globally via a script tag in the head of the HTML document. Use defer to ensure it loads after the HTML body.

```
<head>
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Call JS Functions with Dart.js
Flutter can now access your global JS functions and variables. Call a function by name with callMethod and optionally pass it a list of arguments.

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

 js.context.callMethod('alertMessage', ['Flutter is calling upon 
  JavaScript!']);
```

Comment: hi i have this http://jsfiddle.net/bt7BU/225/ javacript code how can use the above given method to implement it specially passing the event, i am confused..